# how to check if word is in string in dataframe, drop row if not?

Tags: python

Hi I have a dataframe like so:

| product | brand |
| --- | --- |
| colgate toothpaste 150gram | colgate |
| darlene toothpaste 250gram | colgate |
| sensodyne toothpaste 250gram | colgate |
| colgate toothpaste 450gram | colgate |

how do I use the brand to check if it's in product? If it's not in product, drop the row and it returns output like so:

| product | brand |
| --- | --- |
| colgate toothpaste 150gram | colgate |
| colgate toothpaste 450gram | colgate |

Comment: boolean indexing + https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html?highlight=str%20contains

Comment: hi thanks for helping out. 
I tried this 
s = df['product'].str.contains(df['brands'].str, regex=False)
print(s)
everything is returned as null, did i miss out something?

Comment: _if_ it's going to work, the last `.str` shouldn't be there

Comment: did that, and everything still returns nan

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"product": ["colgate toothpaste 150gram", 
                               "darlene toothpaste 250gram", 
                               "sensodyne toothpaste 250gram", 
                               "colgate toothpaste 450gram"], 
                   "brand": ["colgate", "colgate", "colgate", "colgate"]})

# option 1
df = df[df['product'].str.contains("|".join(df['brand']))]

# option 2
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['brand'] in x['product'], axis=1)]

df
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: great this works well thank you. will be learning about apply.lambda

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to find/check a substring:
[Check String for substrings](https://stackabuse.com/python-check-if-string-contains-substring/)

Furthermore you might refer to the product strings like so:
Supposing the data beeing like this:

```
dataframe = [[],[]]
for i in range(1, len(dataframe[0])):
  if dataframe[i][1] in dataframe[i][0]:
    print("Found!")
    drop_row()
  else:
    print("Not found!")
    drop_row()
```

The drop_row()- Function still has to be replaced...